# sqlite3 - script doesn't get changes to table unless script is restarted

Tags: c, sqlite

I have two C programs, both using the sqlite3 library.

1 - One inserts a row into the table

2 - The other has a while loop waiting for a row to be placed into the same table(program ends when it finds a row).

If I start the while loop program, and then insert the row with the first program, the while loop program doesn't see the row. I can run the program in another terminal simultaneously, AFTER it has been inserted, and it finds it 1st try.

My queries are correct.

Am I not locking the database correctly or something? Every statement closed the db with sqlite3_close() and PRAGMA synchronous = FULL (2).

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/qRATMJku

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you committing after the insert?

Comment: How do I do that? I used the code off the c api quickstart here(bottom): http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Does this not commit?

Comment: "Every statement closes the db with sqlite3_close()", really? Even in the while loop?

Comment: If you don't have BEGIN statements in your sql, you inserts will be committed anyway (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html). If you don't call finalize in your loop, try resetting http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html

Comment: I open/close out the db in each iteration of the while loop. I tried calling sqlite3_reset(stmt); before I close the db, but still no dice. Thanks for the help so far guys!

Comment: @cwhelms: does your reader- AND your writer-program close the database ? SELECT-statements do hold updates back (see last sentence on http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html !

Comment: I was closing the database. Given the trouble and simplication of the table I was using, I just created a text based database to solve my problem. I will look at locking when I have time, to solve this problem for other users.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code:

inserting a row like: (with value of the second column = '123')

```
char query[] = INSERT INTO tablename ('msg', 'sid') VALUES ('msgvalue', '123')
```

will break the loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int callback (void *a,int ac,char **av,char **column) {
    if (ac == 2 && av[1] && atoi(av[1]) == 123) // expect av[1] to be '123'
        *(char *) a = 1;
}

int main(void) {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    sqlite3 *handle;
    char query[] = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
    char found = 0;

    if(sqlite3_open("/tmp/sampledb.sqlite3",&handle)) 
        exit(1);

    for(;;) {
        sqlite3_exec(handle,query,callback,&found,NULL);
        if (found)
            break;
        printf("sleeping\n");   
        sleep(1);
    }
    sqlite3_close(handle);
}
```